# Target an empty <li>

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I know this one must be a simple one for the jQuery gurus here, but I honestly have no idea how to accomplish it.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="panel_contents">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to target the empty `<li>` and attach a class to them, for example *class="empty"*. I don't want to modify the HTML to manually add the classes for presentational purposes if I don't have to.

I started a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3vDv8/1/) here for demo purposes.

Thanks a million for any help with this.

--

**EDIT 3 [9/16/14]**

Today, I admit that maybe using jQuery might not be really necessary since empty elements can be targeted with CSS using the `:empty` pseudo-selector, which is actually quite well supported across all browsers all the way down to IE8 (albeit partial support) - http://caniuse.com/#search=empty

**EDIT 2**

Here's [**Another Solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/UH2uN/3/).

This solution looks for `<a href>s` inside the `<li>`, if it has one, it will NOT add the class, if there are no `<a href>s`, then the class *empty* is added.

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to Daniel for the solution. Here's a [**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3vDv8/7/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `:empty` psuedo-selector.

```
$('li:empty').addClass('empty')
```

Comment: Dang! So simple! :D Thanks a lot Daniel :p

Comment: @Ricardo: no problem. jQuery is your friend!

Comment: win sauce! just added another css rule ul>li:empty{ display:none;}