# Remove styling from empty TD

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Target an empty <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489162/target-an-empty-li)

I have a table with values. There may be a few cells that have no values in them.

I need to remove styles from those empty cells.

Is there a way to select empty TD with jQuery?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="val">1</td>
    <td class="val">2</td>
    <td class="val"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is NOT exact duplicate. If there's a space in <td> "duplicate" solution won't work!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:empty` selector:

```
$('td:empty');
```

In case that you want to remove the class, you can use `removeClass` method:

```
$('td:empty').removeClass('val');
```

However if the TD element contains space characters, `:empty` doesn't select that element, in that case you can use `filter` method:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
     return !$.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).removeClass('val')
```

Comment: make sure no whitespace in TD or `empty` fails

Comment: Good point! How can I strip blank spaces?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
$(".val:empty").removeClass("val");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:empty`.

```
$('td:empty')
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHmVK/) [reference](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)